# CodeMirror: onChanges - How to detect what the changes are?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, codemirror

I have an app where I allow the user to tyoe into a CodeMirror textbox.
I have a connection to the server using [SignalR](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/signalr) and am pushing up the full text of the textbox upon changes event.

The trouble is that changes are being pushed up to the server every time the user types a letter.
I managed to filter out the empty space and new line change with an `if` statement like this:

```
    editorChanges(doc, changes: any[]) {
        if (changes[0].text.some(str => str)) {
            this.signalrHub.push(this.editor.value());
        }
    }
```

What I think I need is a solution using [RxJs](https://rxjs.dev/).
I am not all to familuar with RxJs.
Does anyone have experiencce with this?
Has anyone had to do this kind of thing before?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `fromEvent`, `map`, `debounceTime` and `distinctUntilChanged` operators.

```
import { of, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

let codeTextBox = document.getElementById('codetextbox');

let sourceStream$ = fromEvent(codeTextBox, 'input')
  .pipe(
    map((x: any) => x.target.value),
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  );

cont mysubscription = sourceStream$.subscribe(x=>{
  console.log(x) //<-- this is the latest text in the textbox
});

//mysubscription.unsubscribe(); <-- add this line when your view is getting destroyed
```

Also, do take care not to `subscribe` multiple times. Ideally the `subscribe` should happen only once, when the textbox is available in DOM. And do NOT forget to `unsubscribe` else you'll have a memory leak.